# Android Watch Face publishing into Play Store

Tags: android, publish, watch, face

Yesterday I have just finished my first watch face to publish in the Play Store.

I Have the watch module (with the Watch face service) and also an empty handheld module (no activities). Both manifests share the same permissions, the gradle handheld configurations is including the wear module and both have the same package name and version.

I generated the signed APK (wear module) and tried to publish into Play Store. Everything went fine but i was unable to download because (none of my devices were compatible with the app) which is not true.

Then I generated the APK of the Handheld module, and the problem persists.

What I am doing wrong? I could not find more detailed info in the Internet, I would glad if someone could help me.

Should I remove the (uses-feature = wear) form the handheld manifest?

Thanks in advance,
Andre

Comment: Did you follow this instructions: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Comment: None of my devices was compatible because I am de App editor and cannot download it myself. That was it.